# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-hooks

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster6-shard-00-02.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28) at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:484:8)

Comment: that could have many reasons, but check if your IP is added to the DB whitelist

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.